# SharePoint 2010 - MSSQL 2008 connectivity

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Our SharePoint server has some issues connecting over to the MSSQL instance (different server ). 
The error message is :Cannot generate SSPI context .(Microsoft SQL Server )-even when trying to connect from the Management Studio (over to Database Engine). If I try to connect from my laptop then I can connect fine with my user to that database , if I try to connect from the SP server it does not work(same error message ).If I try to connect to the Analysis Services I
get Authentication failed - the system detected a possible atempt to compromise security . Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you.

I've verified the database rights for the SP user, DNS lookup , ip connectivity .

On the SQL server I get a login failed for that user Login failed for user 'mydomain\SPUSER'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ] .

On the SharePoint web interface I get Cannot connect to the configuration database .

Thank you for your help!

Update 1. Seems to be a network connectivity issue as telnet doesn't work (with LDAP/LDAPS) over to the domain controllers .Network connectivity issue confirmed , closing the question :) , be sure to test LDAP / LDAPS if the WIA with MSSQL is not working (depending on the configuration of course )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was a network connectivity issue that preventing the SP server from accessing the credentials from the AD , but it let all other connections free :) . Be sure to test LDAP / LDAPS if the WIA with MSSQL is not working (depending on the configuration of course )